# howto use pydev field __updated__?

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, liclipse

I'd like to have some field, (a variable, or string, anything else), in my source code (a Python module), that keep track of last update in this module, when i save it after some modification.
[This image shows it looks possible in preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io2E0.png)

Where do i put this `__updated__="here some date"` field ?

- I've tried to put it as a global (module level) variable
- I've tried to put in the module docstring (as `@__updated__:''`, `@__updated__=''`, `__updated__:''`, `__updated__=''`) and so on...

thank you

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried adding:

`__updated__ = "2010-10-10"`

and saving the file updated the date after having the related setting enabled (note that the initial date format must already match it, as not all `__updated__ = "something"` will be replaced, only the ones that match `yyyy-MM-dd`).

So, my guess is that you didn't start with a valid date there...

Comment: It work perfectly, thank you !
What i tried  was `__updated__ = "xxx" `, which doesnot work.